# Why is =SUMIF(C5:C19,NOT(ISFORMULA(C5:C19))) returning zero?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet that I track my hours.  Each cell initially is populated with a formula, i.e. `=IF(WORKDAY(B24-1,1,holidays2019)=B24,OFFSET(C24,-1,2),0)`
and then as the month progresses I enter my actual time.

- In the following excerpt all values through 5/10/2019 are entered.
- The formula `=SUMIF(C5:C19,NOT(ISFORMULA(C5:C19)))` shows zero.  I do not understand why this does not work.
- I appreciate any help! Column B in my spreadsheet corresponds to the dates shown below and Column C to the time entries.
- Expected Result:  48.9

[image]

Comment: I can tell you why it doesn't work, but I can't suggest you a solution if you don't provide an expected result. What do you want to do, sum only hours where a formula wasn't entered or?

Comment: Your formula is basically trying to sum column C where column C contains True/False (the result of the NOT(ISNUMBER()) will always be a Boolean). SInce column C doesn't contain any True/False values, you get 0. Of course, if it did contain True/False values, the sum of those would also be 0 since the SUM part ignores booleans anyway.

Comment: @Rawrplus, yes :)  Trying to sum the values where a formula does not exists, only a value.  ISNUMBER returns true for both values and formulas.  TYVM for the formatting!!  Much clearer!

Comment: @Rory, I thought I had followed the SUMIF syntax correctly where SUMIF(range, criteria, [optional]range).  The criteria is suppose to be logic returning true/false.  So I am not quite able to put your comment together against the SUMIF documentation.

Comment: you followed the syntax correctly.  The logic does not work though.

Comment: @Forward Ed do you know 'why' the logic doesn't work?  I am not an excel guru but understand programming concepts.  Was hoping to not pursue a macro solution and based upon Dr. Google, this should have worked.

Comment: @ForwardEd thank you for the clarification! it makes sense to me now, will attempt to divine another non-macro way to handle this.

Comment: as @Rory said, NOT(ISNUMBER()) will be either TRUE or FALSE. Do you see any TRUE or FALSE in the column you are comparing? All I see are numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(J6:J20,--NOT(ISFORMULA(J6:J20)))
```

The key to this solution is the -- in front of the NOT().  A boolean that is processed by a math operator gets converted to 1 or 0.  --, +0, -0, *1, /1 would have all worked to do the conversion.  So now you wind up with an array of values you may want to sum being multiplied by an array of 1 and 0 to indicate the ones you want.  The 1 are manual entry and the 0 are your formulas entries.

[image: POC]

Now SUMPRODUCT performs array like calculations.  As a result avoid using full column/row references inside it or you will wind up with a lot of excess calculations.  Adjust the ranges in the answer to suit your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the MSDN definition of the Criteria in [`=SUMIF`](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/isformula-function-e4d1355f-7121-4ef2-801e-3839bfd6b1e5)

> criteria   Required. The criteria in the form of a number, expression,
>   a cell reference, text, or a function that defines which cells will be
>   added. For example, criteria can be expressed as `32`, "`>32`", `B5`, `"32"`,
>   `"apples"`, or `TODAY()`.
>
> > Important: Any text criteria or any criteria that includes logical or
> >     mathematical symbols must be enclosed in double quotation marks (").
> >     If the criteria is numeric, double quotation marks are not required.

So, the reason, why your `SUMIF` returns `0` is, because none of the cells match the criteria, as they return a number and meanwhile they expect `FALSE`

Another issue here being, that the `ISFORMULA` will return `TRUE`, even when a range contains a single formula while all the rest has none. So basically you need to drag the formula down for each cell individually and sum them up only when a value is `TRUE`

Starting from cell `D1`:

```
=ISFORMULA(B1)
```

[image]

And then you can simply sum them up with the formula you provided.

```
=SUMIF(D1:D16,TRUE,C1:C16)
```

[image]

Obviously, you can hide the column `D` to make it more aesthetically pleasing.

Comment: Great answer,  I would just add that after the MSDN description that when a comparison operator like <, >, >=, <=, or <> is not supplied the default value/understanding is =.

Comment: Thank you Rawrplus for your response and information. I have learned alot this morning from you and the others.

Answer (score 1):

Your formula fails because the criteria you're matching against, is TRUE/FALSE. Obviously the values in C5:C19 don't contain any booleans, so the sum is 0.

To solve this, you can add the correct criteria in cell D5 and below: `=ISFORMULA(C5)`
Then use `=SUMIF(D5:D19,FALSE,C5:C19)` to sum the values in column C.

Comment: Thank you Sven for your response and the information.